# Defining IPv6 chains in ip6tables-restore/iptables-restore files, is it possible?

Tags: iptables, firewall

The format for the files generated by `iptables-save`/`ip6tables-save` and loadable through `iptables-restore`/`ip6tables-restore` stipulates that one can prepend `-4` or `-6` respectively so as to maintain the rules for IPv4 and IPv6 in the same single file.

The lines with `-4` are ignored by `ip6tables-restore` and the ones with `-6` are ignored by `iptables-restore`.

Now, this seems only to apply to *rules*. How can I create a chain (`:CHAINNAME -`) only for **either** stack?

That is, if I have something like (excerpt):

```
*filter
:ICMPv6 -
-6 -A INPUT -p icmpv6 -j ICMPv6
```

how can I make sure that the chain is only created for the IPv6 stack but not the IPv4 stack?

Is this at all possible?